# VoIP point to point Python H.323

Tags: python, voip, pjsip, python-sip, h.323

I would like to stream audio both ways between 2 computers using Python and Ubuntu, ideally using H.323 I have looked at pjsip but can only see a way of connecting to SIP servers not a simple point to point system.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_SIP) may contain some useful information and pointers.

Answer (score 1):

There are very few H.323 libraries available: There are the OpenSource [H323Plus](http://www.h323plus.org/) and [OPAL](http://www.opalvoip.org/) and the commerical Radvision SDK. None of them provides direct support for Python, but I guess the functions could be rolled into a C wrapper to be called by Python. H323Plus has the better H.323 support, but OPAL has already started on a C wrapper.